# Stata. What is the return code for `ineqdeco`?

Tags: stata, ineqdeco

I have a panel data set. I am estimating inequality measurements by states.

```
ineqdeco income if state==12
//Now, what command can i use to assign inequality measurement values to local variables?
// local gini = `r(...`
// local atkinson = `r(...`
```

The `ineqdeco` returns an array of values... How can I get them into a `local`?

Comment: What does the bounty imply? The question is already answered.

Comment: @NickCox, I think Buras really likes your answer and wants to reward you for it. Read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118889/236833

Comment: That's right. You contributed a lot to this website. I really appreciate it

Comment: @Buras Thanks for the bounty and the comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ineqdeco` is a user-written program from SSC. It is r-class, so leaves in its wake various results, which can be listed by `return list` immediately afterwards. Such results will be overwritten by the next r-class program.

```
 local ge2 = r(ge2)
```

is an example of how to copy such results to local macros.

Comment: Thank you! it works. Does it mean that ones we have `local ge2 = r(ge2)`, I cannot have `local gini = r(gini)`, unless I run `ineqdeco` again? Is there any way around? Thank You!

Comment: In practice, you can make as many such assignments as you like. Why not try it?

Comment: My apologies, it is possible. Thanks